# Dynamic_cast not needing to perform a run-time check?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

Quoting from item 45 in C++ Gotchas:

> First a dynamic_cast is not necessarily dynamic, in that it may not
>   perform a runtime check. When performing a dynamic_cast from a derived
>   class pointer (or reference) to one of its public base classes no
>   runtime check is needed, because the compiler can determine statically
>   that the cast will succeed. Of course, no cast of any kind is needed
>   in this case, since conversion from a derived class to its public base
>   classes is predefined.

I thought the above description is where a dynamic_cast is normally used (and therefore would do run-time checks??).

Could someone please explain the difference between the above quote and the "typical" need to use a dynamic_cast? This got me confused as to when I need to use dynamic_cast and why I don't need to use it for the above scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    // ...
};

class Derived : public Base {
    // ...
};
```

"Typical use":

```
void foo(Derived*);

void f(Base* pb)
{
    if (Derived* pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pb)) {
        foo(pd);
    }
}
```

"Above quote":

```
void bar(Base*);

void f(Derived* pd)
{
    Base* pb = dynamic_cast<Base*>(pd); // the dynamic_cast is useless here
                                        //  because a Derived IS-A Base, always
    bar(pb); // Note: could as well call directly bar(pd); (implicit conversion)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` is mostly used for *downcast* and *cross-cast*. The gotcha mentions upcast.

Having structs B1, B2, D:B1, B2:

- upcast: D* -> B1*, D* -> B2*
- downcast: D* <- B1*, D* <- B2*
- cross-cast: B1* <-> B2*  (will work if your most derived class is D).